# remove failed: EACCES (Permission denied) - can not delete file from sd card

Tags: java, android, permissions, delete-file

my app records audios using android's build-in audio recorder. the recorded audio file is created in the external(removable) sd card. I successfully copy it to the app's internal storage. but when I want to delete the recorded file from sd card this error happens:
`remove failed: EACCES (Permission denied) : /storage/43F8-16FA/Voice Recorder/Voice 013_sd.m4a`
Note that I have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. Also, I have runtime permissions and I use android 6.0.

```
// I get this file path from onActivityResult
String fileAbsolutePath = "/storage/43F8-16FA/Voice Recorder/Voice 014_sd.m4a";
// copy the file to internal storage
copyFileToInternalStorage(fileAbsolutePath);
// delete recorded file from sd card
File file = new File(fileAbsolutePath);
if (file.exists()) {
   // THE FILE EXISTS BUT IT FAILS TO DELETE THE FILE
   file.delete();
}
```

Comment: File operation are runtime permissions, did you query for user's confirmation? Note that only requiring `{READ,WRITE}_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not enough, Android >= 6.0 require a per-app runtime requirement, asking for some code in your application for querying user's confirmation.

Comment: Who created that 'Voice Recorder' directory?

Comment: `// I get this file path from onActivityResult` The onActivityResult of which action? Show intent please. Further you take nothing from the intent data that onActivityResult delivers but use a hard coded path. Please elaborate.

Comment: Which Android version on used device? Removable micro sd cards are read only since Android Kitkat about.

Comment: I have runtime permissions, I use android 6.0 (Marshmallow), the 'Voice Recorder' directory is created by android's build-in voice recorder app. also, the file path is correct, I've checked it.

Comment: Correct or not: you did not show how you obtained that path in onActivityResult. Or from which onActivityResult. You were asked to show that. Any reason not to do so?